# Just installed Rstudio 1.0.136, now where is it?

Tags: software-center, rstudio

I just installed the new version of Rstudio (1.0.136) by clicking the link on the Rstudio website (Ubuntu 64bits) and opening the resulting file in 'Ubuntu Software Center'. After a lot of time displaying 'progress' the Ubuntu Software Center gives a green check mark with the words 'installed', so my question is: where is it? If I type rstudio into the search window of 'files' I only get a folder with the previous version of Rstudio (Rstudio-0.99.903) but the new version is nowhere to be found.

Comment: What's the output of `ls /usr/bin | grep rstudio` ?

Comment: It's empty. Nothing happens, I just get a new terminal input line

Comment: It might as well be with a capital `R`. Try grepping without case sensitivity: `ls /usr/bin | grep -i rstudio`.

Answer (score 1):

Is the package called *"rstudio..."*? If you've got synaptic installed you can search for *rstudio* and then look at the package properties to see what files are installed where.

Or, from the terminal you can search & show files with `dpkg` (`dpkg-query`) and these commands:

```
   dpkg-query actions
          See dpkg-query(1) for more information about the following actions.

          -l, --list package-name-pattern...
              List packages matching given pattern.
          -s, --status package-name...
              Report status of specified package.
          -L, --listfiles package-name...
              List files installed to your system from package-name.
          -S, --search filename-search-pattern...
              Search for a filename from installed packages.
```

So find the package name with
`dpkg-query --list rstudio`
or maybe with wildcards like
`dpkg-query --list "*rstudio*"`

Then show what files were installed using the exact package name (assuming it's *rstudio* below
`dpkg-query --listfiles rstudio`

---

Or, just **search everywhere with `find`** assuming the filename contains "rstudio" somewhere:

```
find / -type f -iname "*rstudio*" 2>/dev/null
```

where `2>/dev/null` is just to ignore the warnings about permission denied to search some directories.